# Transforming path and redrawing does not work

Tags: android, canvas, path

I have Path that I'm creating once, and adding Rect to it.

On some event I'm offsetting the path by `Path.offset(...)` or `Path.transform(...)`
and then invalidating my canvas for redrawing the path.

But the path is not redrawing in the new place.

I checked the path bounds by using `Path.computeBounds(...)` and I see that the rectangle moved. So I don't understand why `Canvas.drawPath(...)` is not redrawing the path in the new place.

The only way I managed to make the path redrawn in the new place is to make new path and add the transformed path to it, but I don't really want to do it every time.

```
m_objPath.offset(p_fltDx, p_fltDy);

//////////////////////////////  
// With this lines it makes the path redrawn in the right place - but why should i ??
Path objPath = new Path();
objPath.addPath(m_objPath);
m_objPath = objPath;
//////////////////////////////

m_objCanvas.invalidate();
.
.
.

m_objCanvas.drawPath(m_objPath, m_objPaint);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could You provide minimal compilable example code, so it will be possible to observe the issue?

Comment: No problem. I will simplify my code and edit my question.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem though I scale instead of translating. Two paths, seemingly identical, one scales correctly, the other does not. Code path is exactly the same for both, just the data differs a little. It seems it's a bug of some sort.

Comment: Additional observation: `Path.translate(Matrix)` sometimes works while `Path.translate(Matrix, Path)` never does, at least on my 4.2.2 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the issue with `Path.offset(..)` against Android 4.1 and Android 2.3:

- On Android 2.3 `offset(..)` works ok.
- On Android 4.1 it fails to show new position of the path. Still it is moved! If I return to main screen (central hardware button on my Samsung) and start app again - it shows correct position.

So just drop using Path...